# read special summary property

Tags: c#, dsofile

I am working on a small C# tool to read and write file properties (CAD files with custom properties).

Right now I am using the DSOFILE extension to read the custom properties and the "summaryproperties" option to read the normal ones.

Unfortunately I can't read the one shown on the picture below. Can anyone help me?

[image: the property I would like to read]

Comment: (For people interested in helping with solving the problem: ) PAR files are Siemens Solid Edge files with CAD data in them.  If you wanted to obtain some sample projects that manipulate PAR files, you can find them here: https://github.com/SolidEdgeCommunity/Samples

Comment: What is shown is a shell extension made by Siemens which is used to display and change the properties. The property values are stored in the file directly. You would have to know the file format to change them.